# Using android Java.Lang.Object in Xamarin: ObjectsSystem.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I came across this error 4 days ago and decided to skip and continue my app but well I am back it with no solution yet. I get this error `System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible` in my adapter extended to a baseAdapter specifically in my `GetView function`.

What can I do to solve this? How must I implement IConvertible?

**Adapter**

```
  class LocationAdapter: BaseAdapter
  private  JavaList<LocationFinder>findLocation;



  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)comment.BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
         View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Data,null);
         Name= itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getName);
         Level = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getLevel);
         Date = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getDate);



         Name.Text = findLocation[position].Name;//error points here
         Level.Text = findLocation[position].Level;
         Date.Text = findLocation[position].Dates;

         return itemView;

                    }

        public override int Count
        {

            get
            {
                return findLocation.Count;
            }
        }
        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return  position;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
```

**LocationFinder**

```
class LocationFinder 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Dates { get; set; }

        public LocationFinder()
        {

        }

        public LocationFinder(string Name, string Location){

            this.Name = Name;
            this.Location = Location;
            Dates = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMMM dd);
        }


    }
```

Comment: "public override Java.Lang.Object" is the most disturbing character sequence I have ever read.  If it is what it says, then you have my props, otherwise, my scorn.

Comment: So here's the deal.  Either you or some framework is calling one of the Convert methods, probably ChangeType but who knows, and your type doesn't implement it.  It's usually GUI frameworks that do this, so try wrapping whatever you think is wrong in a wrapper class and slap IConvertible onto it.

Comment: @hoodaticus, i will have to give that a try asap. I got this error trying to convert data from my firebase using Datasnapshot to  my JavaList. Without using Datasnapshot, i get no error nor any IConvertible issue.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you been able to identify the offending line?

Comment: @TimothyJames  i have tried implementing IConvertible in my adapter but that still gave me the same error. The offending line `findLocation[position].Name;`. apparently the object findLocation

Comment: What is `findLocation`? You don't ever describe what that is.

Comment: I have a class called LocalFinder. With that in mind,  i call its declared variables (Names, Data, Location) with findLocation in my adapter

Comment: Is `JavaList` something you made? I'm having trouble finding any documentation on it.

Comment: JavaList ? No.. i imported from `using Android.Runtime;`
`

Comment: Can you confirm that `Name.Text` and `LocationFinder.Name` share the same type?

Comment: @TimothyJames i don't really get you please. By the way, i have updated my code with the LocationFinder class.

Comment: I'm trying to understand as much of this to help you as I can. As much as you may not like Ed, he was right in that you didn't offer very much information. You have an issue where some typing is coming into play (which is why IConvertible is being requested: something wants to be converted). With more information under my belt, I can rule out certain problems. I now suspect you're issue is with the JavaList. I would guess you'll see the same issue if you write `LocationFinder currLocFinder = findLocation[position];`. Is there a reason you don't use a `List<LocationFinder>` instead?

Comment: I was using List in the first place before JavaList. I am actually doing a data fetch from firebase with Datasnapshot  and then pass the data to my listview. But using the List, i was getting an error `cannot convert from Java.Object to LocationFinder` which i was having a hard time resolving. I decided to go with JavaList to escape that error

Comment: Classic XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TimothyJames, I wouldn't just run away from the problem but i couldn't get any documentation to help me solve that issue

Comment: It has nothing to do with running away from a problem, but not giving enough background information. That is the problem you're experiencing. You need to convert your Java.Object to a LocationFinder. That's what the IConvertible is trying to do. If you would have given ample background information, I wouldn't have spent all this time working backwards to what you just now told me. StackOverflow encourages you to share what research you've done and what you have done to try to solve the problem, so this doesn't happen.

Comment: And that is the problem i facing now with how to implement IConvertible. There isn't any documentation to assist so i could do the conversion

Comment: Did my answer not fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LocationFinder objects that you're pulling from Firebase are coming in as Java.Objects. The invalid cast is coming because you're attempting to operate on the Java.Objects as if they are LocationFinder objects. I suggest casting them as they come out of your `JavaList` or better yet, cast them as they go into a `List`.

I'm not an expert on which kind of casting is best, but one of these ought to work.
`findLocation.Add(objectFromFirebase as LocationFinder);`
`findLocation.Add((LocationFinder)objectFromFirebase);`

`LocationFinder temp = (LocationFinder)findLocation[position];
LocationFinder temp = findLocation[position] as LocationFinder;`